# How to send data to APM from NodeJs using mavlink?

Tags: node.js

How to write params to ArduPilot (APM) from NodeJS using node-mavlink?
For example to change geofence enable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the documentation for the mavlink parameter protocol here: http://qgroundcontrol.org/mavlink/parameter_protocol

The basic idea is that you send a `PARAM_SET` message to set a parameter value, then wait for an ACK in the form of a `PARAM_VALUE` message that has the value you just set.

[image]

The documentation for the `PARAM_SET` and `PARAM_VALUE` messages is in the mavlink defintion XML file: https://github.com/omcaree/node-mavlink/blob/c30f8a63ca6a1ebc1669fefcd07bb3780540e41b/src/mavlink/message_definitions/v1.0/common.xml#L966

Here's an (untested) example of creating and sending a `PARAM_SET` message to enable the geofence.

I checked the [ArduCopter/APM:Copter parameter documentation](http://copter.ardupilot.com/wiki/configuration/arducopter-parameters/#fence_enabledisable_fence_enable) to learn that the parameter you want is called `FENCE_ENABLE`, and that a value of `1` means it's enabled.  I checked the [mavlink message definition for the `MAV_PARAM_TYPE` enum](https://github.com/omcaree/node-mavlink/blob/c30f8a63ca6a1ebc1669fefcd07bb3780540e41b/src/mavlink/message_definitions/v1.0/common.xml#L759) to learn the enum value for the `param_type` argument to specify a `UINT_8` (my best guess for the type of a boolean parameter).

```
myMAV.createMessage(
  "PARAM_SET",
  {
    'target_system': 1,
    'target_component': 1,
    'param_id': 'FENCE_ENABLE',
    'param_value': 1.0,
    'param_type': 1
  },
  function(message) {
    serialport.write(message.buffer);
  });
```

(See the ["Initialization" section of the node-mavlink documentation](https://github.com/omcaree/node-mavlink/#initialisation) for information on how to load and initialize the library.)

I haven't written the code to receive the ACK from the drone, but the ["Parsing Data" section of the documentation](https://github.com/omcaree/node-mavlink/#parsing-data) will guide you on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I have build an node-based ground control station https://github.com/kvenux/nodegcs

Please feel free to use it.

To make the geofence enable, you need to create a message to set the related param.

Hope it helps.